# How to test for user admin, and redirect in Meteor and Velocity?

Tags: meteor

I'm interested in playing with: https://github.com/alanning/meteor-velocity-quick-start

I'd like to do a simple test along the lines of a user going to '/admin' and getting shown an access denied page. How do you test for admin, routes, and redirects?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

check out my tutorial on velocity. I cover quite a lot of grounds, chapter on acceptance testing is coming as well:

https://doctorllama.wordpress.com/2014/08/03/creating-and-testing-meteor-applications-with-bdd-using-velocity-and-jasmine/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at the Nightwatch-selenium or Cucumber.js frameworks as they both have velocity support.  Unforunately at this point, cucumber hasn't kept up with recent velocity updates.

Do you have a repo that you are building tests against, on github?